# PROBLEMS WHILE EXPORTING DATABASE FROM WORKBENCH

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Im trying to import a database from workbench, but I got this error every time it finishes:

```
A partial dump from a server that has GTIDs will by default include the GTIDs of all transactions, even those that changed suppressed parts of the database.
```

After that, the .sql file is created but i cannot open it because it says there is one **invalid argument**.

Can someone please help me? I´m having a really bad time trying to make a backup.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

to fix this issue you need to disabling GTIDs in the MySQL dump process by using the --set-gtid-purged=OFF option.
here how:

```
mysqldump --set-gtid-purged=OFF -u [username] -p[password] 
[database_name] > [output_file].sql
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Where can I write this?

Comment: You should run this command in your command prompt (Windows) and make sure the mysqldump utility is in your system's PATH variable. You can check this by running the following command:
mysqldump --version
and then run this 
mysqldump --set-gtid-purged=OFF -u [username] -p[password [database_name] > [output_file].sql

Comment: I see. What if my database is on the server? how do I access to it? Because is telling my that the db does not exists but that is because is not in local. Sorry but I started to learn MySql a few weeks ago!

Comment: I just did it, thank you. Now, this is supposed to fix it in workbench as well?